# Question on a proof regarding the additivity of outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

The proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080073/if-e-cup-i-n-is-a-countable-union-of-pairwise-disjoint-intervals-prove-that). The questions asks us to prove

If $ E=\cup I_n$ is a countable union of pairwise disjoint intervals ,prove that $m^*(E)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)$.

and the interested direction is $m^{*}(E)\geq \sum_n l(I_n)$.

The proof is the following:

\begin{align*}
 m^*(E)&=m^*\left( \bigcup_{n} I_n \right)\\
 & = m^{*} \left( \bigcup_n (a_n,b_n) \right)\\
 &\geq m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon, b_n-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon \right) \right)\\
 & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}\left( \left( a_{n}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon,
 b_{n}-\frac{1}{2^n}\varepsilon\right) \right)\\
 & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[l(I_n)-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\varepsilon\right]\\
 & = \sum_{n}l(I_n)-2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

I don't understand the fourth line, $m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon, b_n-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon \right) \right)  =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}\left( \left( a_{n}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon,
 b_{n}-\frac{1}{2^n}\varepsilon\right) \right)$. What's the justification for this line? Isn't this something we're supposed to prove?

Comment: The key is at the end of the answer, namely, if sets are at positive distance from each other (which is stronger than merely being disjoint), then the outer measure is additive. See here for a proof in the case of two sets https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110318/prove-that-ma-cup-b-mamb-whenever-exists-alpha0-such-that?rq=1

Comment: @Tab1e Are you sure? I've re read it and I don't see what you mean

Comment: @Reveillark you answered my question. Indeed I skipped the last line. Thank you.