# Proving that the outer measure of an arbitrary union of intervals is equal to the infinite sum of the outer measures of the intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I found in the solution to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080073/if-e-cup-i-n-is-a-countable-union-of-pairwise-disjoint-intervals-prove-that/2080081#2080081) that

> $$m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon, b_n-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon \right) \right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}\left( \left( a_{n}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon,
>  b_{n}-\frac{1}{2^n}\varepsilon\right) \right)$$
> where $m^\ast$ denotes outer measure.

There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110318/prove-that-ma-cup-b-mamb-whenever-exists-alpha0-such-that?rq=1) for the $n=2$ case. However, that proof cannot be used to justify the equality above, of course. This proof also cannot be extended to the infinite case using mathematical induction, as far as I understand. Could someone please prove a proof for the equality above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use proof for a case with $n=2$. Indeed, for each $N\in \mathbb{N}$ it is wright that $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} I_n(\varepsilon))\geq m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{N} I_n(\varepsilon))$, where $I_n(\varepsilon)=(a_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n},b_n-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n})$, because $m^*$ is monotonic as an outer measure. With the induction you can show that $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{N} I_n(\varepsilon))=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N m^*(I_n(\varepsilon))$. So for each $N\in \mathbb{N}$ you have that $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} I_n(\varepsilon))\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^N m^*(I_n(\varepsilon))$. Then you can take a limit as $N$ goes to $+\infty$. You will get that $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} I_n(\varepsilon))\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} m^*(I_n(\varepsilon))$. But converse is true because of countable subadditivity of $m^*$. So the equality holds.